# Google Service Configuration File Editing iOS

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, analytics

Lately in our app we had integrated Google Services. Now we got a new Google Account from which we will monitor our app, but in my app there is an old configuration file with an old Tracking ID and Google App ID generated. My question is that, can we change it from there the Google App ID value manually and if yes how can we find the recent google app id from our Google Account or we have to generate another new Configuration File from Google?

Here is a screenshot of the file:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by App ID? it is the same with project ID. then you can check it in [Google Developers Console](https://login.corp.google.com/request?s=up.corp.google.com:443/uberproxy/MiF9akPCg0zF0I/&d=https://pantheon.corp.google.com/%3FdebugUI%3DDEVELOPERS%26upxsrf%3DADBfK3Y6YtpKh5Lse4FL:1467339688799&maxAge=1200&authLevel=2000000&keyIds=MIG,ubk).

Comment: @KENdi see this is the first time I'm importing Google Services, and I'm worried only for the Google_App_ID value that you can see on the screenshot, is that the value that has to be equal with the Project's ID?